# Is it real to install PostgreSQL 9 on the virtual machine Windows Server R2?

Tags: postgresql, administration, windows-server-2008, virtual-machine

I have Virtual Box with GuestAddition. And virtual machine "Windows Server 2008 R2"

When I use real computer with Windows Server 2008 R2 I can install postgresql-9.2.3-2-windows.
But when I install postgresql-9.2.3-2-windows on virtual machine I have error "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly"

Please, help me.

Comment: The problem is solved. It is interesting to know, that it is not easy to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS on the virtual Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I delete previous PostgreSQL x64 9.1.9 from virtual machine.

(

```
1) from control panel
2) then delete user "postgres". It is appeared after first installation 
3) restart virtual machine 
4) delete one "unknown user". In fact it is the user "postgres". It is appeared after postgres deletion.
```

)

Secondly, 
(

```
1) I create user "postgres"
2) Add user "postgres" to the group "Administrators"
3) Copy postgresql-9.1.9-1-windows-x64.exe on the disk c:
4) install
>> runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
>> c:
>> cd c:\
>> postgresql-9.1.9-1-windows-x64.exe
```

)

Then I install PostGIS and Geoserver

Comment: If it is important, I wrote full instructions on Russian language with pictures. I take the main actions from
 [link]http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default installation folder.
Rather than using c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL..., try using something like C:\PostgreSQL...

Comment: http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html

This is the main part of my actions. Now the problem is solved.